# RTO and RPO - Data Loaders, CSG will have only RTO whereas Databases will have RPO as well as RTO. Is it correct?

Tags: disaster-recovery

Data Loaders, CSG will have only RTO whereas Databases will have RPO as well as RTO. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very badly-written question, I think if you ROT-13'ed it it would make more sense.

That said let's attempt to pick through the debris.

By 'Data Loaders' I'm going to *assume* you mean some form of bulk-import/ETL software. If that's a correct assumption then typically the code will be able to resume either at a batch level or even row-level following a DB outage. In this scenario RPO has little meaning but RTO does.

Databases do indeed have both.

So maybe get back to us, feel free to use actual sentences if you wish, we'll review it again if you do.